# Django Cache Machine: Enabling QuerySet caching on third-party or core Models

Tags: django, caching

I'm using Cache Machine to cache QuerySets which involves adding this to your model:

```
class MyModel(CachingMixin, models.Model):
    objects = CachingManager()
```

How can I apply this caching to Models I don't have access to? e.g. User or third-party modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for the job. Inherit by 3rd party model, overwrite `objects` and use this class instead of an original one.

Comment: The caching will be done only with your code in that case (only the code which uses proxy models). To make cached variant usable for all the code the `evil-monkey-patching` can be done. like ``from user import models; models.User = CachedUser``.